# django rest model-view-set list action raise 404 if pass query parameter

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

if I pass any query parameter get 404

### views.py

```
class BusinessViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Business.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, HasUsernamePermission]
    filter_backends = [SearchFilter, DjangoFilterBackend, DistanceFilterBackend]
    search_fields = ['username']
    ordering_fields = ['name']
    pagination_class = LimitOffsetPagination
    filterset_fields = ['name', 'category']

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            return BusinessCreateSerializer
        return BusinessSerializer
```

### urls.py

```
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

from businesses.api.views import BusinessViewSet

app_name = "businesses"
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'', BusinessViewSet,basename="business")
urlpatterns = []
urlpatterns += router.urls
```

for example if i request

- `/api/businesses/` - response code is 200
- `/api/businesses/?search=a` - response code is 404

Comment: Can you show your urls for this view?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `show_urls` command for further checks if you have [django_extensions](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/).

It seems that you are using DjangoRestFramework default `SearchFilter` backend, hence you must add `search_fields` to the `BusinessViewSet` class.

Also, check the route from your browser to see if the form and its button (Filter button) are available and working or not.

[DjangoRestFramework Search and Filter Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fwMm.png)

Comment: I add search_fields and my problem not solved

Answer (score 0):

[The docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#searchfilter) mention

> The SearchFilter class will only be applied if the view has a search_fields attribute set.

As you don't have `search_fields`, `SearchFilter` is not used.

Comment: I add search_fields and my problem not solved

Comment: Does you `Business` model have `username` column and is there any business with `username=a` ?

Comment: yes there is, and imagine if not exists it must return an empty list not raise 404 error

Answer (score 0):

I debug my code and found my problem

### HasUsernamePermission code

```
from rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from django.urls import resolve


class HasUsernamePermission(BasePermission):
    """
    User must has username
    """
    message = _('User must has username')

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        # Instance must have an attribute named `owner`.
        if resolve(request.get_full_path()).url_name == 'user-detail' \
                and request.method == 'PATCH':  # user probably set username
            return True
        return bool(request.user.username)
```

when you query params passed resolve method raise 404 exception
I change my code to down blow and  my problem has solved

```
class HasUsernamePermission(BasePermission):
"""
User must has username
"""
message = _('User must has username')

def has_permission(self, request, view):
    # Instance must have an attribute named `owner`.
    if view.__class__.__name__ == 'UserViewSet' and view.action == 'detail' and request.method == 'PATCH':  # user probably set username
        return True
    return bool(request.user.username)
```

thank you friends for your feedback on my question